# Reporting based on fields from different child objects

Tags: reporting, visual-workflow

I have two child objects of the Account object : Loans & Deposits. I would like to show any Deposit (DepositDate__c)which happened within 30 days of a Loan's closing (CloseDate__c) for that Account. I can't do this with current reporting filters.

If there was only one Loan per Account I would be able to put in a Workflow process which would populate a simple field in the Deposit record to indicate if it was or wasn't within 30 days of the Loan for the Account. But there are multiple Loans for some Accounts, so I essentially would have to step through every single Loan for that Account to see if the Deposit was within 30 days of any of the Loans.

Does anybody have any ideas for this ? I thinking it would require a trigger on the Deposit object to accomplish this, but I don't think I could pull that off. If it could be done with Process Builder it would be much better.

Thank you very much.

Comment: To clarify: you're comparing your Loan's CloseDate__C and Deposit's DepositeDate__C? Is there anything that connects the two together - otherwise you will have a many-to-many relationship.

- to word it better, do you have a junction table to connect the two?

Comment: Yes, those are the fields I am attempting to compare. Both objects are a child object to the Account object. 

Does that answer your question ? Thank you.

Comment: You would need a junction table or some sort of reference to connect the two. Following your current logic it's like you're giving your bank creditcard payments but you have 4 different creditcard accounts. Unless you have a way to reference your payments to your 'loan' account, your bank would be magically guessing which loan to pay with your deposits. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: We can't join the objects because they aren't really related besides their mutual link to the Account object.You compared it to credit cards and their payment but that's different. In this case the Deposits aren't payment for the Loans.They just are all separate accounts within their common Account parent record.So I understand what you're saying, but linking them doesn't really make sense.Ideally, I could step through all of the Deps of the Acct and compare it to all of the Loans & when the two fields fit the criteria it would populate a lookup field in the Dep with the recordID of the Loan.

Comment: I might not have explained properly that Deposits are Deposit accounts - not specific deposit transactions. So you've got Loan accounts and Deposit accounts all below the Account record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you wanted to stick with clicks vs code you could combine the process builder with a flow. You should be able to query the related loans in an autolaunch flow that meet the criteria then perhaps check a box on the deposit record if any related loans were returned.

Comment: Jenny - thank you very much. Do I need to have flow triggers activated in my org in order to launch Flows with a Workflow Rule ?

Comment: @Zoom_v in the visual flow guide it looks like calling it from workflow is in pilot so you would need to ask to be part of the pilot program but it should be available with process builder.